# WPF - changing title of window with accessing to the title of Style

Tags: wpf, textblock

I want to create specific Window style for all of my windows page,

On app.xaml I provide this:

```
  <Style x:Key="Style.Window.Default" TargetType="Window">
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="Window">
                            <Grid Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                                <Grid Name="gridBar" Height="40" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="1,0,1,0"

                                  >
                                    <Grid.Background>

                                        <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0, 0" EndPoint="0, 1" Opacity=".1">
                                            <GradientStop Offset="0" Color="{DynamicResource AccentColor}" />
                                            <GradientStop Offset=".3" Color="{DynamicResource AccentColor}" />
                                            <GradientStop Offset="1" Color="Transparent" />
                                        </LinearGradientBrush>
                                    </Grid.Background>


                                    <!-- title -->
                                    <ItemsControl Background="Transparent" MouseDoubleClick="MaximizeClick"  >
                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" Margin="8,8,8,0" x:Name="txtTitle"
                                                Style="{StaticResource ModernWindowTitle}"
                                                  />
                                    </ItemsControl>

  </Grid>
                            </Grid>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
```

And on my windows I provide this :

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow1"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
       Height="300" Width="300" 
         Style="{StaticResource Style.Window.Default}">
    <Grid>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Question is how could I access to "txtTitle", is it possible to adding value to title of window and "txtTitle" gets it.

Comment: `<TextBlock Text="{TemplateBinding Title}" />` works. However, it's unclear why there is an ItemsControl, but no ContentPresenter to show the actual `Content` of the Window.

Comment: @Clemens thank you , it's works perfect. I have deleting it for showing better . anyway please write an answer and I decide to mark it. thanks again